# How to make Bash interpret variable as string for comparison?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that stores the output of a file comparison. The variable becomes something like: thing="/path/to/file - differ: byte 2, line 3".

In later lines I want to check that thing is not empty. However, when I try comparing them, it interprets thing as a command and not simply as a string.

My code is somewhat as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

thing="/path/to/file - differ: byte 2, line 3"
if ["$thing" != ""]; then
    echo
    echo "Something went wrong"
else
    echo "Everything worked"
fi
```

Rather than saying thing is not an empty string, I get an error message that says something like

```
bash: [/path/to/thing - differs: byte2, line 3: No such file or directory.
```

How can I ensure that a comparison is happening between strings and that  thing is not being interpreted as a command?

Comment: Try "${thing}".

Comment: The code with `if ["$thing" != ""]; then` is clearly incorrect — you need `if [ "$thing" != "" ]; then`, though you could also test `if [ -n "$thing" ]; then` (`-n` for not-empty).  (There's also `-z` for 'is zero characters — empty'.) Don't post approximations — it gets people annoyed.  Post actual code.  **And use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/)**  Spacing is critical in shell scripts — no spaces around assignments; spaces around arguments to commands.

Comment: `["$thing" != ""]` should be `[ "$thing" != "" ]`. Works for me this way. You could use `[ -z "$thing" ]` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
thing="/path/to/file - differ: byte 2, line 3"
if [[ -n "$thing" ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
else
    echo "Everything worked"
fi
```

Notice the double `[[]]` pairs. That will make use of Bash's internal `test`.

Use `help test` on Bash's command prompt to get more information.

EDIT: As explained by Jonathan in the comments, using any of `[ … ]` or `[[ … ]]` or `test` uses a built-in internal command in Bash. Section `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` of `man bash` (or [Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) and [Bourne Shell Built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)) explains that.  However, while `[ … ]` and `test` are logically the same (the only difference is that `[` expects its last argument to be `]` but `test` has no analogous expectation), the tests implemented by `[[ … ]]` are subject to different parsing rules from `[ … ]` and `test`, and `[[ … ]]` implements some extra test capabilities missing from the other.

Comment: Using `[` and `]` also uses Bash's internal `test` (aka `[`) command — it's just different from the `[[` … `]]` testing command.

Comment: On most Linux distributions, ```[``` is a symlink for ```/usr/bin/test```. Does that still true in this case?

Comment: Yes, but `bash` doesn't run `/usr/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/[` when you type `[` — in fact, it is not unknown for there to be differences in behaviour between the internal (built-in) `test` and the external (built-out?) `test`.  The `[` (aka `test`) command has been built into shells for a very long time — certainly since Unix SVR4 and I think considerably earlier.  And SVR4 dates from the mid-80s or thereabouts.  It wasn't built into the 7th Edition (Version 7) Bourne shell, though; then it was a separate standalone command.

Comment: Good to know. I prefer using the internals whenever possible to avoid calling out external programs. That gives me the (not proofed) sense of performance improvement. :-)

Comment: There absolutely is a difference between using `[[ ]]` and using `[ ]`/`test`: quoting, support for patterns and regular expressions...